# Como Aumentar tempo timeout webForm

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-identity

como aumentar o tempo de timeOut, minha sessão esta caindo em torno de 5 min, não é na string de conexão.

Asp.Net
Autenticação AspNet Identity

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms timeout="20" loginUrl="/Acesso/Login.aspx"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

Answer (score 2):

Anderson se você alterar o valor `<sessionState timeout="1440"></sessionState>` terá 24 horas... 360 6 horas.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="1440"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms timeout="1440" loginUrl="/Acesso/Login.aspx"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tentou resetar o IIS?

No IIS, na aplicação/website tem uma configuração de Session State tbm. Veja se ele está pegando as suas configurações.

Caso nem isso funcione, tente mudar o Session.TimeOut pelo código, no início do processamento da requisição.